# Passing Controller Action Results to Redirected Action in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, form-submit

I have a Symfony controller action that generates a set of PDF files and then shows the resulting links to the generated PDFs. Problem is, I would like to avoid users from reloading the page and thus re-generating the PDFs, so it seems that using $this->redirect(...) would make sense...except then how would I pass the resulting array of PDF links to the new redirected action?

And forgive me if this is a duplicate question. I tried browsing around a bit and couldn't find a corresponding question along these lines. Appreciate any help or thoughts on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('page', array('arrayLinks' => $arrayLinks)));
```

Check the Symfony2 API: http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't this generate a GET string query with the parameters given for generateURL()? Not that I'm vigorously opposed, but it seems like there should be a more elegant way to hand data over to the redirected action on the backend without resorting to passing data via a GET query. I'll try it out and post back.